# Debugging Django/Python on Dreamhost

Tags: python, django, debugging, dreamhost

Debugging Django on Dreamhost is proving quite the challenge. To my knowledge, print statements aren't available, and neither are logs... any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Django Debug Toolbar](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-debug-toolbar/0.8.1), as already mentioned, is damn useful.

But as long as Django is running in [debug mode](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#debug), the brute force method equivalent to the `print` statement is to simply throw an exception.  Put whatever output you want in the exception's text, whenever you need a quick idea of you code's state, and voila... instant output and stacktrace.  This isn't a comprehensive solution, but it is a quick `print` statement style hack.

Comment: Yep, I use `assert False, <some value I'm interested in>` constantly while developing in Django.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the [Django Debug Toolbar](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-debug-toolbar/0.8.1)?

For a summary of the features, watch the [video here](http://robhudson.github.com/django-debug-toolbar/).